# Laravel Basic Auth- Invalid Credentials Error in json

Tags: php, laravel, basic-authentication

I am using basic auth in my api. When I enter a wrong credential, it throws

> UnauthorizedHttpException.

I want this in JSON format.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add header `"Accept: application/json"` before sending your request.